# Django- Not displaying a PDF page on the front-end

Tags: django-views, django-urls, http-get, django-settings, django-apps

I am trying to display a PDF page from within the 'document.HTML' page

The file structure is

1.Client2--> catalog --> Static --> catalog --> my css files etc

2. Client2--> catalog --> Templates --> catalog --> images (pdf's in here) & all my .HTML files

The pdf's are referenced as src..{images/..pdf} etc

The document HTML page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    {% load static %}
</head>
<body>
<!-- Type is pdf and is located in the documents.html directory aka (catalog) but within a sub-folder 'images'-->
<embed type="application/pdf"
       src="images/Logs_Guide.pdf"
       width="250"
       height="200">

<embed type="application/pdf"
       src="images/AD_Guide.pdf"
       width="250"
       height="200">
<img src="images/ER_Diagram.jpg">

</body>
</html>
```

But when I try it within the Django front end and click the pdf I get

```
"GET /catalog/documents/images/Logs_Guide.pdf HTTP/1.1" 404 3366
```

Answer (score 0):

---

1. So documents HTML is **loading static**, meaning all files within the
   **static directory** are loading
2. However, the images folder, where the PDf files are stored are
   within **templates/catalog/images**
3. So I would need to move this folder within **static/catalog/images** and
   then can change the source to:
4. This is load static and find the file within the **(step 3)** file path
5. And replace **(below code)** snippet and update to the documents.html

---

```
<embed type="application/pdf"
       src="{% static 'catalog/images/Logs_Guide.pdf'%}"
       width="250"
       height="200">
```

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    {% load static %}
</head>
<body>
<!-- Type is pdf and is located in the documents.html directory aka (catalog) but within a sub-folder 'images'-->
<embed type="application/pdf"
       src="images/Logs_Guide.pdf"
       width="250"
       height="200">

<embed type="application/pdf"
       src="images/AD_Guide.pdf"
       width="250"
       height="200">
<img src="images/ER_Diagram.jpg">

</body>
</html>
```